# Polymer v1.0 computed properties not recalculating

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have this:

```
is: 'paper-filter',
properties:{
  filters:{
    computed: 'getFilters(data,byArray,obj_filters)'
  },
```

and it is not updating when `obj_filters` is updated
still not updating ever with arguments are != `undefined`

Here a video demoing the problem

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2sFtTur-E_CSVBKbVdlRzZzTkE

and the jsfiddle

http://jsbin.com/todonohike/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

If I just update the `obj_filter` :

```
  var new_obj_filters = this._setFilter(title, index, by, max, this.obj_filters);
  this.obj_filters = new_obj_filters; // no 'computed properties' are fired.
```

If I clone the Object it fires just fine:

```
  var obj_filters = this._setFilter(title, index, by, max, this.obj_filters);
  this.obj_filters = clone(obj_filters); // TODO why clone ??? but fixed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your changes to `obj_filters` need to be made using the Polymer API (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#observing-path-changes) and [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path)).

For example,

```
obj_filters[by][title] = true
```

should be changed to something like

```
this.set(["obj_filters", by, title], true)
```

Also have a look at the [API description](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/). To find the relevant part, search for "set(".

**Edit**

I've found two more issues that cause your problem.
First declare your computed property as follows (note the *).

```
filters:{
    computed: 'getFilters(data,byArray,obj_filters.*)'
},
```

Second, when you call `this.set(["obj_filters",by,title], true);` for the first time `obj_filters.by` has not been defined yet and `obj_filters.by.title` can't be set because the path does not exist. One way around this is to initialise it first.

```
if (!this.obj_filters[by]) {
    this.set(["obj_filters",by], {});
}
this.set(["obj_filters",by,title], true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Maria I tryed that no affect http://jsbin.com/todonohike/2/edit?html,output

Comment: That's going to go a long way to help me simplify the code